# how to execute html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

my database calls certain functions by inserting commands inside angle brackets. i.e.<#SUBMIT  title="Request Report"> will create a button that submits form (criteria) data to the engine for reporting.

Before that button gets clicked I want to check some date criteria so I have inserted an image link into my document which calls my javascript code. If all conditions are met I want it to run/click the above button. Here is my code, it all works until the <#submit> part. Any suggestions would be gratefully welcome.

```
function checkdate() {

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var startdate = document.forms[0].datescopestart.value;
    var startdate2 = startdate.split("/");
    var startdate3 = new Date(startdate2[2], startdate2[1] - 1, startdate2[0]);
    var totaldays = ((currentTime - startdate3) / 86400000);

    if (totaldays > 100) {

        alert("You can only choose a start date within the last 100 days")
    } else if (startdate == "") {
        alert("You cannot leave the start date blank")
    } else {
        ("<#SUBMIT>")
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
The source code behind the rendered <#Submit> button is:

```
<input type=button value="Request Report" class=button onclick="showhide('reportbutton');selectAll(document.forms[0].customfieldexp);selectAll(document.forms[0].user);document.forms[0].submit()">
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the javascript.

Comment: Call whatever method the link/button calls? Call `click` on it? Hard to say since we don't know what DB, how it creates its HTML, etc.

Comment: Do you want to insert the button into the document or what is your problem. The title of your question does not make a lot of sense, you cannot "execute" HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You don't "execute an HTML tag."  It's just mark-up.  Is there an actual `<#SUBMIT>` tag in the rendered mark-up?  If so, that doesn't sound like valid HTML.  Or is that a server-side tag that gets replaced by something else when rendered to the client?  What does your actual rendered HTML look like and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the same code that is executed in response to the button's click() event.  So you will need to code something like this (it's repetitive and somewhat brittle, but the framework that you're using doesn't give you much leeway):

```
if (totaldays > 100) {
    alert("You can only choose a start date within the last 100 days");
} else if (startdate == "") {
    alert("You cannot leave the start date blank");
} else {
    showhide('reportbutton');
    selectAll(document.forms[0].customfieldexp);
    selectAll(document.forms[0].user);
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

I can't tell what showhide() and selectAll() do, so you might want to explore the code to understand how they are part of the submit, as established by your framework.

Style note: the JavaScript interpreter automatically supplies a statement-terminating semicolon at the end of a line, but it's not good practice to depend on that.  Code your semis explicitly.